# style long list elemts so it appears in new line when there is no place

Tags: html, css

[image]I've go a   `<div id="update-div-2" class="update-div"><ul></ul> </div>` in with `<li>` tags are being added dynamically and.
this are my styles:

```
#update-div-2{
    width: 569px;
    height: 174px;
    clear: left;
    border-right: #1c3f77 2px solid;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}

#update-div-2 ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

But when there is very long `<li>` tag added, it doesnt break into many line, but instead it is one very ling line. How can I make it break when it there is no more place into new line?

Comment: Are you talking about long text with no whitespace?

Comment: Added an image. Take a look. It scrolls anyway. I scrolled so you can see there is more stuff to show.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class like this one:

```
#update-div-2 li{
    word-wrap:break-word;   
}
```

Comment: I don't believe commas are treated as whitespace in order for break-work to work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#update-div-2 li {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```